# The equivalence between two sufficient statistics for the same parameter $\theta$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics

**Exercise.** Let $X_1,\cdots,X_{n}$ be i.i.d.r.v.'s from $N(\theta,1),$ where $\theta$ is unknown.Show the statistic $T(\mathbf{X})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}/n=\bar{X} $ is sufficient for $\theta$.

---

The answer as following:

Suppose that we transform variables $X_1,\cdots,X_{n}$ to $Y_1,\cdots,Y_{n}$ with the help of an orthogonal transformation so that $Y_{1}$ is $N(\sqrt{n}\theta,1), Y_{2},\cdots,Y_{n}$ are i.i.d. $N(\theta,1)$ and $Y_{1},\cdots,Y_{n}$ are independent.
We take $$y_{1}=\sqrt{n}\bar{x},$$ and ,for $$k=2,\cdots,n,\quad y_{k}=\left [(k-1)x_{k}-(x_1+\cdot+x_{k-1})  \right ]/\sqrt{k(k-1)}.$$

And then, the author said

> the conditional distribution of $\mathbf{X}=(X_{1},\cdots,X_{n})$ given $\bar{X}$, does not depend on $\theta$ ${\color{Red}{\text{is equivalent to}}}$ the conditional distribution of $(Y_1,\cdots,Y_{n})$,given $Y_{1},$ is independent of $\theta.$

I don't understand why the equivalence between them holds. How to prove it rigorously?

---

I know  that the conditional distribution of $(Y_1,\cdots,Y_{n})$,given $Y_{1}$,is independent of $\theta.$

Since

$$f_{\theta}(y_1,\cdots,y_{n})=(2\pi)^{-n/2}\exp \left [-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=2}^{n}y^{2}_{i}-\frac{1}{2}(y_{1}-\sqrt{n}\theta)^{2}  \right ];$$
$$f_{Y_{1}}(y_{1})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left [ -\frac{1}{2}(y_{1}-\sqrt{n}\theta)^{2} \right ];$$

$$f(y_{1},\cdots,y_{n}|y_{1})=\frac{f_{\theta}(y_1,\cdots,y_{n})}{f_{Y_{1}}(y_{1})}=(2\pi)^{-\frac{n-1}{n}}\exp \left [ -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=2}^{n}y^{2}_{i}\right ]$$ is  independent of $\theta.$

---

Applying *Fisher–Neyman factorization theorem* and *change of variables formula*,the equivalence is obvious.But the author gave this exercise before introducing  the factorization theorem,there must be some other ways to get the equivalence.

---

Every (measurable)
set $\mathcal{S}$ in $\mathbf{R}^{n}, \mathbb{P}_{\theta}[(X_1,\cdots, X_n)^{'}\in \mathcal{S}|\bar{X}=t]$ is independent of $\theta$ a.s. $\mathbf{y}=Q_{n}\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}=Q_{n}^{T}\mathbf{y}$ and $Q_{n}^{T}Q_{n}=I_{n},y_{1}=\sqrt{n}\bar{x}.$ Then $$\mathbb{P}_{\theta}[(X_1,\cdots, X_n)^{'}\in\mathcal{S}|\bar{X}=t]=\mathbb{P}_{\theta}[(Y_1,\cdots, Y_n)^{'}\in Q_{n}^{T}(\mathcal{S})|Y_{1}=\sqrt{n}t].$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformation you have written can be expressed succinctly in the form:

$$\mathbf{y} = H(\mathbf{x},\bar{x})
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\mathbf{x} = G(\mathbf{y},\bar{x}).$$

The equivalence mentioned in your question holds because, once we condition on $\bar{x}$, there is a one-to-one relationship between $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$.    For example, if we have $\mathbf{x} \ \bot \ \theta|\bar{x}$ then we get:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{y} \in \mathscr{Y}|\bar{x},\theta)
&= \mathbb{P}(H(\mathbf{x},\bar{x}) \in \mathscr{Y}|\bar{x},\theta) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(H(\mathbf{x},\bar{x}) \in \mathscr{Y}|\bar{x}) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(\mathbf{y} \in \mathscr{Y}|\bar{x}) \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

which means that $\mathbf{y} \ \bot \ \theta|\bar{x}$.  Similiarly, if we have $\mathbf{y} \ \bot \ \theta|\bar{x}$ then we get:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{x} \in \mathscr{X}|\bar{x},\theta)
&= \mathbb{P}(G(\mathbf{y},\bar{x}) \in \mathscr{X}|\bar{x},\theta) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(G(\mathbf{y},\bar{x}) \in \mathscr{X}|\bar{x}) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(\mathbf{x} \in \mathscr{X}|\bar{x}) \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

which means that $\mathbf{x} \ \bot \ \theta|\bar{x}$.

Comment: This clearly answers OP's query. +1.